# Data for bingo tickets

Tags: data

Is there a data source for 90 and 75 ball bingo tickets? rather than coding to generate the tickets myself just trying to find a source to save me the time.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling for "90 ball bingo ticket generator" gives plenty of relevant hits.

I don't think there are any "official" bingo tickets out there though, but writing a generator is probably rather trivial..

The most obvious thing would be to make completely random cards, which, due to the way bingo works, would work just fine. With a bit more effort it would be possible to generate a set of cards that make sure that for a given number of players, each number appears the same number of times - to avoid the awkward situation where everybody in the hall shouts 'bingo' at the same time..